Disable "swipe to lock" screen on Galaxy S10e
Using a Galaxy S10e, pressing the side button turns off the screen, as expected:

Pressing the side button again turns the screen on, and asks the user to swipe to continue:

I neither have nor want biometrics on my phone.
What is the canonical way to disable the swipe-to-open screen so that pressing the side button goes directly home?
Using adb to change the settings would be fine.

Disable the lock settings using adb as follows:
adb shell locksettings set-disabled true
adb shell locksettings clear

After running these commands, the "swipe to unlock" screen will no longer appear.
